# How can I place 3D models on the right place of the face using ARKit and face detection?

Tags: swift, arkit, face-detection, 3d-model

This is my first time working with face detection on ARKit and I want to place a 3D model of a hat and glasses on the right place of the face. How can I use the node (with geometry: faceGeometry)to do that or is there any other way to position the models?